# Get Json file from laravel controller

Tags: php, json, laravel-5.4

I need to print json file passed by a Laravel controller method hosted in different server. Send code like this,

```
  function curlrequest($url, $data){  

        $handle = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

        $output = curl_exec($handle);


        if($output === FALSE) {
                    die(curl_error($handle));
                  }else{

                    return $output;
                  }  

         curl_close($handle);  

        }
```

In receiver php file (native php),  I have following code,

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r(json_decode(file_get_contents("http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/myproject/public/send")),1).'</pre>';
```

And in my web.php file I have

```
Route::get('/send', 'Test\SendController@main');
```

I didn't run this code yet. But I see that we cannot access routes using file_get_content method. Can anyone tell me what is the proper way to pass json in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems a bit unclear, but from what I can understand you want to get the JSON output from `http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/myproject/public/send` and print it in your PHP code.

An easy way to do this is to use [GuzzleHttp](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/).

Example:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$result = $client->request('GET', 'http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/myproject/public/send');
echo $result->getBody();
```